# How is Minecraft able to function without a META-INF folder?

Tags: java, minecraft

I really don't understand how this works. I'm trying to build a `.jar` right now. It consists of two classes: `Test.class` and `Sayer.class`. And it works just fine if I access `Test.class` directly, or properly pack `Test.jar`, but the only way I can get a jar to execute is if I pack it with a manifest (`jar cfm Test.jar manifest Test.class Sayer.class`).

If I don't do that, I get an error when trying to run the jar: `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile Test.jar`. This also happens if I build the "good" jar, and remove `META-INF/`

This perfectly makes sense on its own. After all, you need some way of telling Java where to look for the entry point...right? But then you have Minecraft's modding community, which routinely recommends removing `META-INF` to make a given mod work.

But, how is Minecraft able to function without a `META-INF` folder? According to my experiments, this shouldn't even be *possible*. Shouldn't this *corrupt* `minecraft.jar` just like it corrupted my `Test.jar`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since MineCraft is run from a launcher, the launcher itself can pass the appropriate startup class to Java directly without needing a `META-INF` folder.

Comment: i.e. `javaw -cp minecraft.jar StartupClassHere`

Comment: As I understand/think/guess when you load via a launcher it has other Java files it loads to load the main jar of Minecraft. My guess then is that that loads the jar, and then as you pointed out, therefore the Minecraft.jar doesn't need the metainf and forge does pretty much the same. But since you can launch Minecraft without a launcher perhaps a test to see if doing so would replicate his error to demonstrate my guess. Also would make for a more detailed and complete answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, I completely forgot about the launcher. I'm used to executing `minecraft.jar` directly on Linux, though it just occurred to me that said `minecraft.jar` is probably a launcher that starts a different `minecraft.jar`, and modding it would break the game either way.

Comment: @ydobonebi I tested it on my own .jar file. `java cf Test.jar Test.class Sayer.class && java -cp Test.jar Test`. It worked. I assume `cp` stands for `class-path`.

Comment: @B1KMusic it does indeed stand for classpath. It can contain many jar files and directories, chained like your system path using colons (*nix) or semicolons (windows).